# Have multiple operations on a single event

Tags: rxjs

Trying to have a event triggering multiple switchMap with the initial event data.

Each actions creates a promise to some transform that is then written in the file system. The actions are independent and unrelated, but uses the same data, just for different purpose, so they should not be merged.

Currently using taps instead of switchMap, that can lead to multiple event running the at the same time.

```
const SomeApiCall = () => {return {some: 'data'} }
const AllowsDoAction = () => {console.log('Parsing API and writting some things to FS -- PLACEHOLDER')}
const SomeTimeDoThisActionTo = () => {console.log('Parsing API and writting some other things to fs, by asking more data from the API and first, so it is long thing to do, so a new event can arrive first -- PLACEHOLDER')}
const deepEqual = (prev, cur) => prev === cur // normally a proper deepEqual...
const taps = [tap(AllowsDoAction)];
if (someCondition) taps.push(SomeTimeDoThisActionTo)
const observable = timer(0, 500).pipe(
   exhaustMap(SomeApiCall),
   distinctUntilChanged((prev, cur) => deepEqual(prev, cur))
   ...taps
);
```

Comment: is action async or sync ?

Comment: the action are async, each action can run in any orders or at the same time, and they uses async means to write to files. (going to wrap the file writing in a observable that can be unsubscribed using the stream api destroy method, once I can use switchMap)

Comment: Do u want them to run concurrently or in queue

Comment: Either way is fine, so I guess concurrently? The data doesn't change often and will be checked by a process that takes a while between checks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would return the filesystem write *observables (edit 2)*

```js
const SomeApiCall = () => {
  return of({ some: 'data' });
};
const AllowsDoAction = () => {
  console.log('Parsing API and writting some things to FS -- PLACEHOLDER');
  return timer(100).pipe(map(() => 'write 1 finished'));
};
const SomeTimeDoThisActionTo = () => {
  console.log(
    'Parsing API and writting some other things to fs, by asking more data from the API and first, so it is long thing to do, so a new event can arrive first -- PLACEHOLDER'
  );
  return timer(1000).pipe(map(() => 'write 2 finished'));
};
```

And then use [concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html) to wait for all filesystem operation to complete.

```js
const deepEqual = (prev, cur) => prev === cur; // normally a proper deepEqual...
const taps = [(AllowsDoAction)];
const someCondition = true;
if (someCondition) {
  taps.push(SomeTimeDoThisActionTo);
}
const reduxStorageEvent$ = of('replace this with real event');

const observable = merge(timer(0, 500), reduxStorageEvent$).pipe(
  exhaustMap(SomeApiCall),
  distinctUntilChanged((prev, cur) => deepEqual(prev, cur)),
  // use switchMap to cancel previous writes (edit 2) 
  // await latest write operations, before starting new writes
  concatMap((someData) => {
    const writes = taps.map((tapFx) => {
        return tapFx(someData);
    });
    // wait for all writes
    return forkJoin(...writes);
  })
);
```

concatMap is like a queue. The first one in this queue has to finish before the second one can start.

Comment: From what I understand, this will prevents events from the time to be sent? And thus it won't cancel the current writes? And thus once done it would then rewrite the changes?
I had 2 cases where I wanted to do multiple writes : One timer based, the other from a redux store change. Would this work in both cases?

Comment: It prevents tohe current writes from being canceled. Once they are done, it starts the queued up writes. If your have multiple sources(timer + redux) you can use merge, see edited answer

Comment: I would have really like a model that would have canceled previous write request then start the new one, so that we don't edit the file more then needed and I would feel safer in knowing that the latest event is handled. But if this solution works, it's great.

Comment: It's hard to cancel Promises. you'll have to make those observables, too. And then use switchMap instead of concatMap. see (edit 2)